# Combine two tables by joining on the same date or closest prior date (not just exact matches)

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have two table:

- CustomerID
- Lead_Date
- Lead_Source

and

- CustomerID
- Product_Interest_Date
- Product_Interest

I want two create a single table where, for each CustomerID, each Product_Interest in connected to a the Lead_Source that is the closest date (but not after). The final table would be:

- CustomerID
- Product_Interest_Date
- Product_Interest
- Lead_Date (the closest entry in time to Product_Interest_Date)
- Lead_Source (the Lead_Source of the closest Lead_Date)

So far, I can join the tables, and create a new field that calculates the closest date without going over, but when I try to Group using Min, I still get multiple permutations (every Lead_Date to every Product_Interest). Here is the code:

```
SELECT Min(Int(Abs([Test_PI]![Product_Interest_Date]-[Test_Leads]![Lead_Date])))
       AS Lead_PI_Link, 
       Test_Leads.CustomerID,
       Test_PI.Product_Interest_Date, 
       Test_PI.Product_Interest,
       Test_Leads.Lead_Date, 
       Test_Leads.Lead_Source
FROM Test_Leads INNER JOIN Test_PI ON Test_Leads.CustomerID = Test_PI.CustomerID
GROUP BY Test_Leads.CustomerID,
         Test_PI.Product_Interest_Date,
         Test_PI.Product_Interest, 
         Test_Leads.Lead_Date,
         Test_Leads.Lead_Source
HAVING (((Test_Leads.CustomerID)="C6UJ9A002Q2P"));
```

This CustomerID has 4 entries in Test_Leads, and 4 entries Product_Interest. The result of this query gives 16 results in stead of the desired 4. If the dates were an exact match, I could add a criteria that the date difference was "0", however, sometimes these dates are offset by a 1 day, sometimes many days.

I am using Access, and would prefer a "native" solution, but am up for anything at this point!

Comment: Can  you please add the query you wrote to the question as well?

Comment: Can you try to change this clause `(Test_Leads.CustomerID)="C6UJ9A002Q2P"` to the `JOIN` conditions and remove the `HAVING`clause

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test_PI

```
CustomerID  Product_Interest_Date  Product_Interest
----------  ---------------------  ----------------
         1  2014-09-07             Interest1       
         1  2014-09-08             Interest2       
         1  2014-09-15             Interest3       
         1  2014-09-28             Interest4
```

Test_Leads

```
CustomerID  Lead_Date   Lead_Source
----------  ----------  -----------
         1  2014-09-07  Source1    
         1  2014-09-14  Source2    
         2  2014-09-15  Source3    
         1  2014-09-21  Source4
```

The trick here is to use an unequal join as part of a subquery to identify the most recent Lead_Date for each Product_Interest_Date. The query

```sql
SELECT 
    pi.CustomerID, 
    pi.Product_Interest_Date, 
    l.Lead_Date
FROM 
    Test_PI pi 
    INNER JOIN 
    Test_Leads l
        ON pi.CustomerID = l.CustomerID 
            AND pi.Product_Interest_Date >= l.Lead_Date
```

returns

```
CustomerID  Product_Interest_Date  Lead_Date 
----------  ---------------------  ----------
         1  2014-09-07             2014-09-07
         1  2014-09-08             2014-09-07
         1  2014-09-15             2014-09-07
         1  2014-09-15             2014-09-14
         1  2014-09-28             2014-09-07
         1  2014-09-28             2014-09-14
         1  2014-09-28             2014-09-21
```

Notice how two matches are returned for 09-15 and three matches are returned for 09-28. We're only interested in the latest ones, so we'll tweak that query slightly

```sql
SELECT 
    pi.CustomerID, 
    pi.Product_Interest_Date, 
    Max(l.Lead_Date) AS MaxOfLead_Date
FROM 
    Test_PI pi 
    INNER JOIN 
    Test_Leads l
        ON pi.CustomerID = l.CustomerID 
            AND pi.Product_Interest_Date >= l.Lead_Date
GROUP BY 
    pi.CustomerID, 
    pi.Product_Interest_Date
```

which returns

```
CustomerID  Product_Interest_Date  MaxOfLead_Date
----------  ---------------------  --------------
         1  2014-09-07             2014-09-07    
         1  2014-09-08             2014-09-07    
         1  2014-09-15             2014-09-14    
         1  2014-09-28             2014-09-21
```

Now we can JOIN the two tables together with that query to pull it all together

```sql
SELECT 
    Test_PI.CustomerID,
    Test_PI.Product_Interest_Date,
    Test_PI.Product_Interest,
    Test_Leads.Lead_Date,
    Test_Leads.Lead_Source
FROM
    (
        Test_PI
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT 
                pi.CustomerID, 
                pi.Product_Interest_Date, 
                Max(l.Lead_Date) AS MaxOfLead_Date
            FROM 
                Test_PI pi 
                INNER JOIN 
                Test_Leads l
                    ON pi.CustomerID = l.CustomerID 
                        AND pi.Product_Interest_Date >= l.Lead_Date
            GROUP BY 
                pi.CustomerID, 
                pi.Product_Interest_Date 
        ) latest
            ON Test_PI.CustomerID = latest.CustomerID
                AND Test_PI.Product_Interest_Date = latest.Product_Interest_Date
    )
    INNER JOIN
    Test_Leads
        ON Test_Leads.CustomerID = latest.CustomerID
            AND Test_Leads.Lead_Date = latest.MaxOfLead_Date
```

returning

```
CustomerID  Product_Interest_Date  Product_Interest  Lead_Date   Lead_Source
----------  ---------------------  ----------------  ----------  -----------
         1  2014-09-07             Interest1         2014-09-07  Source1    
         1  2014-09-08             Interest2         2014-09-07  Source1    
         1  2014-09-15             Interest3         2014-09-14  Source2    
         1  2014-09-28             Interest4         2014-09-21  Source4
```