# SQL Datediff on multiple levels

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I have a lot of issues using the `datediff` function in SQL Server.

I have two tables that I want to join based on the time gap between observations; the tables contain arrival times of shipments as follows `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`.

I found a different question of which the answer will (hopefully) help me with the join bit. The code provided by said example states the following, and this is where the struggles begin.

```
Abs(DateDiff("d", pi.Product_Interest_Date, l.Lead_Date)) AS Date_Gap
```

**Source**: [Join two tables on the same date or closest date (before or after)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26415612/join-two-tables-on-the-same-date-or-closest-date-before-or-after)

However, I need to find the **date gap** between values based on the full date, so from year to seconds. Am I correct in understanding that the `datediff` function only accepts one level (i.e. only day or minute), or am I doing something wrong?

If the former is the case, is there an easy way to do what I want to do?

Comment: (1) Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text. (2) Tag your question with the database you are running: is this SQL Server?

Comment: Well, what I need is a value for the date gap, and I can get that value for either the minute or the second or the day etc. separate. However, I need to take all of it into account, since shipments can arrive at the same hour but on a different date. So I want to know if there is a way to use a similar function as the example but which takes all the parts of the date into account.

Comment: If you want to calculate a difference at different periods, for example, days, hours minutes and seconds, then also get the difference in the lowest denominator, as you can calculate the rest form that. For example `1494292` seconds is 17 days, 7 hours, 4 minutes, and 52 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

First, the syntax in SQL Server for days is:

```
abs(DateDiff(day, pi.Product_Interest_Date, l.Lead_Date)) AS Date_Gap
```

The syntax that you are using is MS Access syntax.

SQL Server does not have an interval type.  You can get the difference in seconds and then convert to another unit.  For instance, decimal days is:

```
abs(DateDiff(day, pi.Product_Interest_Date, l.Lead_Date)) / (24.0 * 60 * 60) AS Date_Gap
```

You don't provide sample data and desired results that describes the exact results you want, but this should put you on the right track.  If this doesn't fully answer your question, then you should ask a *new* question with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic.